# c++ template extract bool parameter

Tags: c++, templates

I want to extract the bool value from template parameters, and use that value in somewhere else in the code. (More specifically, I want a if-else in compile time).

```
template<bool enable_xx>
struct A {
  void DoSomething() {
    if (enable_xx) {
      // do something 
    } else {
      // do something else
    }
  }

}
```

I'm using C++11, but if such feature exists for higher version C++ pls also tell me, thanks!

Comment: What's wrong with the code you have?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One possibility is the following

```
#include <iostream>
template<bool isTrue>
struct A;

template<>
struct A<true>
{
        void DoSomething()
        {
                std::cout << "You did it!" << std::endl;
        }
};

template<>
struct A<false>
{
        void DoSomething()
        {
                std::cout << "You did not do it!" << std::endl;
        }
};

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
        A<true> a;
        A<false> b;

        a.DoSomething();
        b.DoSomething();

        return 0;
}
```

Produces the following output:

```
You did it!
You did not do it!
```

Comment: If I have many common fields and functions in the struct, and only a few function behavior depends on that bool param, does it means that I have to duplicate most of my code...or can I only specialize that specific function?

Comment: @ZiqiLiu Yes you can also specialize member functions instead of the struct: https://godbolt.org/z/nZga2S

Answer (score 8):

[C++17 provides a way to do this using `if constexpr`:](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/if)

```
template<bool enable_xx>
struct A {
  void DoSomething() {
    if constexpr(enable_xx) {
      // do something 
    } else {
      // do something else
    }
  }
};
```

`if constexpr` only runs at compiletime, and it does exactly what you want.

Answer (score 6):

Well, `if (enable_xx)` can be solved at compile time. Most compilers will optimize your function to prevent checking the condition at runtime, but *you can't be sure*.

The best way to handle this is to use `if constexpr` which is a **C++17 feature**. It allows you to specify that the if statement is depending on one or more `constexpr`.

Giving this code:

```
#include <iostream>

template <bool verbose>
void SayHello()
{
    if (verbose)
    {
        std::cout << "Hello guys!\n";
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "Hi!\n";
    }
}
```

The disassembly (Using x64 msvc v19.20) for `SayHello<true>()` looks like:

```
void SayHello<1>(void) PROC                   ; SayHello<1>, COMDAT
$LN5:
        sub     rsp, 40                             ; 00000028H
        xor     eax, eax
        cmp     eax, 1
        je      SHORT $LN2@SayHello
        lea     rdx, OFFSET FLAT:$SG31024
        lea     rcx, OFFSET FLAT:std::basic_ostream<char,std::char_traits<char> > std::cout ; std::cout
        call    std::basic_ostream<char,std::char_traits<char> > & std::operator<<<std::char_traits<char> >(std::basic_ostream<char,std::char_traits<char> > &,char const *) ; std::operator<<<std::char_traits<char> >
        jmp     SHORT $LN3@SayHello
$LN2@SayHello:
        lea     rdx, OFFSET FLAT:$SG31025
        lea     rcx, OFFSET FLAT:std::basic_ostream<char,std::char_traits<char> > std::cout ; std::cout
        call    std::basic_ostream<char,std::char_traits<char> > & std::operator<<<std::char_traits<char> >(std::basic_ostream<char,std::char_traits<char> > &,char const *) ; std::operator<<<std::char_traits<char> >
$LN3@SayHello:
        add     rsp, 40                             ; 00000028H
        ret     0
```

As you can see, the program will evaluate the condition at runtime.

With C++17 `if constexpr` (`if (verbose)` ==>`if constexpr (verbose)`) the disassembly with the same compiler options looks like:

```
void SayHello<1>(void) PROC                   ; SayHello<1>, COMDAT
$LN3:
        sub     rsp, 40                             ; 00000028H
        lea     rdx, OFFSET FLAT:$SG31017
        lea     rcx, OFFSET FLAT:std::basic_ostream<char,std::char_traits<char> > std::cout ; std::cout
        call    std::basic_ostream<char,std::char_traits<char> > & std::operator<<<std::char_traits<char> >(std::basic_ostream<char,std::char_traits<char> > &,char const *) ; std::operator<<<std::char_traits<char> >
        add     rsp, 40                             ; 00000028H
        ret     0
```

You can see that the `if` statement disappeared from the generated code. The compiler optimized it.

You can also note that the disassembly is strictly the same as a non templated version of this function:

```
void SayHelloTrue()
{
    std::cout << "Hello guys!\n";
}
```

So, if you can use C++17, always specify your `if` as `constexpr` (If they are evaluable at compile time) to optimize your code even in debug mode (No optimization flag). If you can't use C++17, assume that your compiler will have the last word, and will or won't optimize your code, depending on optimization flags and its capabilities.

The disassembly I shared has been generated using: https://godbolt.org/

This website is a great tool to check how a compiler (*Clang*, *GCC*, *MSVC* and more) behave with your code.